# Scatter plot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm fairly new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I have to plot the scatter plot with:

```
residues1  residues2  coovariance
1          1          0.99613318 
2          1          0.98771518
3          1          0.98681384
4          1          0.99225447
```

`residue 1` and `residue2` as `x`,`y` axis and the `coovariance` is to be color scale rather than height. I have previously used scatter plot 3d but don't know how to plot the third axis as a color scale. Please help .

Thanks

Vibhor

Comment: Can you share a bit about what you have tried so far?  This is a question that sounds like a quick google search could answer, but if that is not the case, please share some code, your errors and how your results are not matching your expectations.

Comment: Start with `plot(1:4,rep(1,4),col=c(1:4),pch=19)` and try changing the `col=` argument with values derived from your `covariance` column.

Comment: Use a "scatterplot" with discrete values for both x and y? That is not the usual name for such a plot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an x-y plot with color per column 3 is the best way to visualize this. If `residues2` is a constant, prob. better to leave it out altogether and plot the other values against each other.

Perhaps you could adapt the following to your needs:

```
df1 <- data.frame(r1=seq(4), r2=rep(1,4),
                  c1=c(0.99613318, 0.98771518,  0.98681384, 0.99225447) )
### give order (for plotting)
df1 <- within(df1, c2 <- rank(c1))
### create blank plot
with(df1, plot(r1,r2, xlab="residues_1", ylab="residues_2", cex.lab=1.5))
### strongest red to largest color
with(df1, points(r1, r2, cex=15, pch=19, col = rev(heat.colors(4))[c2] ))
### make legend
l1 <- as.matrix(df1[ ,"c1"])
graphics::legend("topright", legend=l1, lty=1, title="covariance", lwd=3,
                 col = rev(heat.colors(4))[df1$c2], cex=2)
```

giving:

[image]
(I've made the image elements a bit oversize, and manually adjusted dimensions before saving as `.png` in order to display better on here).